# Play video from coredata as nsdata in avplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdata, avplayer

How to play video in AVPlayer from coredata as nsdata formate?
MPMoviePlayerController deprecated so I am going with AVPlayer. I am search some thing said about url path for saved nsdata location I am not clear about that. Anyone explain this? How can I play?

I am new for this I appreciate if share that code.

If any one share good tutorial for custom AVPlayer I didn't find good one so learn from github sample project.

Advance Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this!

```
 NSString *filePath = [self documentsPathForFileName:@"video.mp4"];

 BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
 if(!fileExists) {
    NSData *videoAsData;   // your data here
    [videoAsData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
 }

 // access video as URL
 NSURL *videoFileURL =  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

// create an AVPlayer
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoFileURL];

// create a player view controller
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.player = player;

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
    [controller.player play];
}];


- (NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name
{
  NSArray *paths =     NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

  return [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
}

// if you want to remove file after playing video

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
BOOL success = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
```

Comment: How do I get data from coredata? Is that method [self documentsPathForFileName:@"video.mp4"] how can I?

Comment: I've shown you the code to play video from NSData using AVPlayer. Now you only need to get NSData of your Video from CoreData thats it.

Comment: If you've store Video URL in your core data then simply convert that URL into NSData

Comment: I need that in to offline that only so URL not able to work at that time :(. If I call this code more than once it's store same video multiple times? is that correct? If it's yes how can I over come that?

Comment: please see my edit answer. You can always check if video is already exists, then you can play directly from there once you saved it. Also check code if you want to delete that file.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH... I will check this.. Bool condition and after delete that video from path.. actually remove that video from path that what I now checking in google :) you save my day :)
and one more small clarification is that same for URL from online video and offline video file path? `AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoFileURL];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102678/discussion-between-user3589771-and-iosenthusiatic).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Swift version on how to do this

```
let data = //... your video Data/NSData
let cacheURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("yourvidename.mp4")

do {
    try data.write(to: cacheURL, options: .atomicWrite)
} catch let err {
    print("Failed with error:", err.localizedString)
}

// instantiate the player
let player = AVPlayer(url: cacheURL)
let vcPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
vcPlayer.player = player
vcPlayer.player?.play()

// present it or add it to whatever view you need
present(vcPlayer, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then on `viewWillDisappear` delete the content of the `cachesDirectory` if you want

Comment: This is the simplest solution for swift, once generated 'cacheUrl' you can use it to play the video or extract a thumbnail of the video. Really cool answer!

Comment: this code crashes if the data is huge. can u suggest any solution